# How to use all php files in or outside folder as it is

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have main folder which includes images, css, index,header.php folders and files.

Now i created a new folder named forms in which a file form.php is created.
Now what i did is included the header.php file from main folder. form.php calls the header.php but links like `css/style.css`,`javascripts/js.js` doesn't work inside the form.php.
So give me a solution so that i can include header file in form.php as it is called in index.php.

Comment: include files in your form.php like this 
`../css/style.css`
`../javascripts/js.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you define your Root folder or domain

Ex : define("ROOT","www.maysite.com/");

Then you add this code to your headr.php

```
<php 
define("ROOT","www.maysite.com/");
?

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ROOT;?>javascript/js.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo ROOT;?>css/style.css" />
```

Comment: and guys please do not downgrade my reputation @Sajitha Rathnayake please upvote my qn so that i can get some more reputations thanks

Answer (score 0):

If these files are in your main folder, you can just include them using absolute paths, like this: `/css/style.css` and `/javascripts/js.js`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to have a sort of **ROOT** variable that holds an absolute path to the root of your website.

Every file will be able to use this variable no matter where they are in the directory structure as the path is absolute.

Lets assume that your root variable contains this value: `/var/www/my_awesome_site/`,

Your `index.php` file will reference files like this:

```
$root/css/style.css
```

And your `form.php` would be able to use the same path:

```
$root/css/style.css
```